# Textbox1 Não existe no contexto atual

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

olá estou com um problema na hora de puxar uma id de uma texbox do asp.net acontece que não reconhece segue o código:

```
protected void btnCadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        BLL.Cliente cliente = new BLL.Cliente();
        cliente.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        cliente.Nome = txtNome.Text;
        cliente.Cpf = txtCpf.Text;
        cliente.Senha = txtSenha.Text;
        '
  
    DAL.CadastradoDAL cadastradoDAL = new DAL.CadastradoDAL();

        cadastradoDAL.Cadastrar(cliente);

        lblMsg.Text = "Aluno cadastrado";
        txtCpf.Text = "";
        txtNome.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

código do asp.net:

```
<article class="container-log">
    <div class="content-input">

        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="✉️E-mail"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" CssClass="content-text"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Nome"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNome" CssClass="content-text"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="CPF"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCpf" CssClass="content-text"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Senha"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSenha" runat="server" CssClass="content-text"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>


    <div class="btn">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCadastrar" Text="Cadastrar" OnClick="btnCadastrar_Click"/>
    </div>

    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</article>
```

erro "CS0103".

Comment: *"CS0103"* e onde o erro? pode mostrar a linha e a mensagem completa?

Comment: nesta parte do codigo não reconhece os identificadores das textboxs: 'BLL.Cliente cliente = new BLL.Cliente();
        cliente.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        cliente.Nome = txtNome.Text;
        cliente.Cpf = txtCpf.Text;
        cliente.Senha = txtSenha.Text;'

Comment: Não vejo `TextBox1` em nenhum lugar do código... Tem certeza de que esse é o erro?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize um `<form>` para colocar seus campos de entrada, assim como no exemplo da documentação.

[Documentação do TextBox da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox?view=netframework-4.8)

Exemplo de como ficaria:

```
 <article class="container-log">
            <form ID="form1" runat="server">
                <div class="content-input">
            
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="✉️E-mail"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" CssClass="content-text"></asp:TextBox>
            
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Nome"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNome" CssClass="content-text"></asp:TextBox>
            
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="CPF"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCpf" CssClass="content-text"></asp:TextBox>
            
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Senha"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSenha" runat="server" CssClass="content-text"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            
            
                <div class="btn">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCadastrar" Text="Cadastrar" OnClick="btnCadastrar_Click"/>
                </div>
            
                <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </form>
 </article>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ok vou tentar aqui

Comment: o erro ainda persiste

Comment: Manda toda mensagem de erro para ver em qual linha e os detalhes do erro.

Answer (score 0):

Faz uma busca no projeto todo por "Textbox1", acredito que você deve ter alterado o nome de algum textbox e não alterou em todos arquivos.

Dependendo da versão do framework ou tipo do projeto utilizada o asp cria arquivos separados onde são declarados os componentes (textbox, button, etc).

Acredito que um ou mais destes arquivos o nome está com nome anterior "Textbox1" e não como "txtEmail" ou outro que você está utilizando agora.

Comment: mesmo assim colocamos o textbox1 e nada não funcionou